# Why is uname -M returning an empty string?

Tags: environment-variables, ksh, aix

On the exact same machine (AIX 6.1), in 2 different login shells (both ksh), with different user IDs, I can do `uname -M`; in one shell I get the system model. In the other shell I get BLANK!  The only difference is the user ID and therefore the environment.  I can't put the environment in here.

Example User 1 Shell:

```
$ uname -M
IBM,1234-567
$
```

Example User 2 Shell:

```
$ uname -M

$
```

I have done a truss in both shells.  There is a difference, but I don't understand it.  Here is the bad truss:

```
truss uname -M
.. a bunch of execve's ripped out as it was searching the PATH for uname.
execve("/bin/uname", 0x2FF2155C, 0x20012EF8)     argc: 2
__loadx(0x03480000, 0x2FF21380, 0x00000108, 0xF0713968, 0x20000CD0) = 0x00000000
__loadx(0x0A040000, 0xD042D064, 0x0000008A, 0x20001254, 0x00000000) = 0x00000000
sbrk(0x00000000)                                = 0x200013D0
vmgetinfo(0x2FF20530, 7, 16)                    = 0
sbrk(0x00000000)                                = 0x200013D0
__libc_sbrk(0x00000000)                         = 0x200013D0
getuidx(4)                                      = 28633
getuidx(2)                                      = 28633
getuidx(1)                                      = 28633
getgidx(4)                                      = 100
getgidx(2)                                      = 100
getgidx(1)                                      = 100
getuidx(4)                                      = 28633
getuidx(2)                                      = 28633
getuidx(1)                                      = 28633
getgidx(4)                                      = 100
getgidx(2)                                      = 100
getgidx(1)                                      = 100
__loadx(0x01480080, 0x2FF1FEF0, 0x00000A50, 0x2FF20A60, 0x2FF22ED1) = 0xD0538128
__loadx(0x01480180, 0x2FF1FEF0, 0x00000A50, 0xF068921C, 0xF068914C) = 0xF0759FA0
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF06891EC, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF3C
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF068912C, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF48
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF06891FC, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF78
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF068913C, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF84
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF06891BC, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF54
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF068915C, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF6C
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF06891CC, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AF90
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF06891DC, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AFC0
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF068916C, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075AFA8
__loadx(0x07080000, 0xF068917C, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xF0759FA0, 0x00000000) = 0xF075B020
getuidx(4)                                      = 28633
getuidx(2)                                      = 28633
getuidx(1)                                      = 28633
getgidx(4)                                      = 100
getgidx(2)                                      = 100
getgidx(1)                                      = 100
__loadx(0x01480080, 0x2FF1FEF0, 0x00000A50, 0x2FF20A60, 0x2FF22ED1) = 0xD0538128
getuidx(4)                                      = 28633
getuidx(2)                                      = 28633
getuidx(1)                                      = 28633
getgidx(4)                                      = 100
getgidx(2)                                      = 100
getgidx(1)                                      = 100
__loadx(0x01480080, 0x2FF1FEF0, 0x00000A50, 0x2FF20A60, 0x2FF22ED1) = 0xD0538128
getuidx(4)                                      = 28633
getuidx(2)                                      = 28633
getuidx(1)                                      = 28633
getgidx(4)                                      = 100
getgidx(2)                                      = 100
getgidx(1)                                      = 100
__loadx(0x01480080, 0x2FF1FEF0, 0x00000A50, 0x2FF20A60, 0x2FF22ED1) = 0xD0538128
getuidx(4)                                      = 28633
getuidx(2)                                      = 28633
getuidx(1)                                      = 28633
getgidx(4)                                      = 100
getgidx(2)                                      = 100
getgidx(1)                                      = 100
__loadx(0x01480080, 0x2FF1FEF0, 0x00000A50, 0x2FF20A60, 0x2FF22ED1) = 0xD0538128
access("/usr/lib/nls/msg/en_US/uname.cat", 0)   = 0
_getpid()                                       = 7405946
uname(0x2000132C)                               = 0
statx("CuAt", 0x2FF20870, 76, 0)                Err#2  ENOENT
kopen("CuAt", O_RDONLY)                         Err#2  ENOENT
kioctl(1, 22528, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)        = 0

kwrite(1, "\n", 1)                              = 1
__loadx(0x04000000, 0x2FF20970, 0x00000800, 0x0000D032, 0x00000000) = 0x00000000
kfcntl(1, F_GETFL, 0x00000001)                  = 67110914
kfcntl(2, F_GETFL, 0x2FF22FFC)                  = 67110914
_exit(0)
```

You can see the `kwrite` at the end is only printing out a newline character, `"\n"`.

In the good truss output, it looks like uname is getting the attribute from:

```
/etc/objrepos/CuAt
```

This lead me to the [`lsattr` command and others](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds4/restbase.htm).

**Why is uname -M blank?  What environment variables would affect this?**

Comment: Are all these `__loadx` with a non-zero return code because of a bad `LIBPATH`?

Comment: The problem does not appear to be solely b/c of a `PATH` or `LIBPATH`.  I just tried with those from my good shell.  Still blank.

Comment: Try in both shells: `which uname` and `uname --version`.

Comment: @ott, both return `/bin/uname`.  There is no `--version option` according to `man uname`.  Also you can see in the truss output that it is using `/bin/uname`.  I'm stumped.

Comment: Could one of the shells have a builtin uname? Both are ksh? Can you add the environment of both shells, if it's not too long?

Comment: @ott. Both are ksh. I will have to strip sensitive info from the env before posting it.  Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try running the command in a clean environment: `env -i uname -M`.

Comment: are both shells same user? login shell? is by chance one of them (the second) a restricted shell?

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, `env -i uname -M` returns an empty string in both shells.

Comment: @bdowning, I have edited the question.  Originally it was 2 different users, but I have copied user #2's env so that the only difference is the env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.  I was scanning through the 'good' environment and saw this env var:

`export ODMDIR=/etc/objrepos`

Knowing that the 'good truss' was looking in here for the machine model number, I ran this command in the bad shell and now uname -M works:

```
$ uname -M
IBM,1234-567
```

Sorry I did not post the environment, but it is huge and contains a lot of sensitive information.